# Mysql column reordering numerically when a row deletes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
id  Bill No   Branches_id
 1    1          1
 2    2          1
 3    3          1
 4    1          2
 5    4          1
```

when user deletes bill no 2 all other record's bill_no update in numerical order like this

```
id  Bill No   Branches_id
 1    1          1
 3    2          1
 4    1          2
 5    3          1
```

is there any easy way to reorder all records without a loop in programmatically

Comment: You've got duplicate bill numbers in there, but that aside, why do you think you need this behavior?

Comment: Please fix your example. You have two bill #1s.

Comment: So `Bill No` is not being used as a foreign key on another table?

Comment: It's more than re-ordering, your row with `id` 3 has changed (`Bill No` is now 2 instead of 3). Can another query interfere with your delete query?

Comment: @nicomp bill numbers are based on branches_id

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes.

Comment: Sorry: Yes it is OR Yes it isn't

Comment: @RiggsFolly `Bill No` is not using anywhere else as reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `id` is the primary key and you want to update another column within each bill.  This can be reasonable.

You can use variables:

```
declare @rn := 0;

update likethis lt
    set bill_no = (@rn := @rn + 1)
    where lt.branches_id = 1
    order by lt.id;
```

Note that all foreign references to the table should be using `id`.  If `bill_no` is used to connect to another table, then you shouldn't change the value (even with cascading foreign keys), unless this is a very rare occurrence.